Typescript formula insertion in XLSX issue
I need to insert a formula into the XLSX table. I use typescript + "xlsx" library for that. I have a function that creates a sheet. I need to insert function "VLOOKUP" or "LOOKUP" or "ПОИСКПОЗ" (russian). But the code below produces error when I try to open the xlsx table using Excel.
Funny thing that numerical formulas are working.
function createResultsSheet(resultList: any[]): XLSX.WorkSheet {
    //students sorted by GPA
    const studentsDataSortedByGPA = sortByGPA(resultList);
    const headings = ["Email", "Name", "Group", "GPA", "Priority", "Result course", "Priority 1",
        "Priority 2", "Priority 3", "Priority 4", "Priority 5"];
    const resultSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([headings]);
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(resultSheet, studentsDataSortedByGPA, {origin: -1, skipHeader: true});
    for (let i = 2; i < studentsDataSortedByGPA.length+2; i++) {
        resultSheet["E"+i] ={t:"s", f:"VLOOKUP(F"+i+";G"+i+":K"+i+";0)", v: "=ПОИСКПОЗ(F"+i+";G"+i+":K"+i+";0)"};
    }
    const maxColWidths = getMaxColumnWidth(resultSheet, headings.length, studentsDataSortedByGPA.length+1);
    resultSheet['!cols'] = maxColWidths.map(width => ({wch: width}));
    return resultSheet;
}

I tried to look into their official documentation but nothing found.

Would help, if you share the error.
